# What's the point of strspn?

Tags: php, function, built-in

At work today we were trying to come up with any reason you would use [strspn](http://www.php.net/strspn).

I searched google code to see if it's ever been implemented in a useful way and came up blank. I just can't imagine a situation in which I would really need to know the length of the first segment of a string that contains only characters from another string. Any ideas?

Comment: I decided to see if I could find a point, and to be honest, I really can't. There may be some instances where there's a speed difference than another function, but dammnit, I can't find a reason.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although you link to the PHP manual, the `strspn()` function comes from C libraries, along with `strlen()`, `strcpy()`, `strcmp()`, etc.

`strspn()` is a convenient alternative to picking through a string character by character, testing if the characters match one of a set of values.  It's useful when writing tokenizers.  The alternative to `strspn()` would be lots of repetitive and error-prone code like the following:

```
for (p = stringbuf; *p; p++) {
  if (*p == 'a' || *p == 'b' || *p = 'c' ... || *p == 'z') {
    /* still parsing current token */
  }
}
```

Can you spot the error?  :-)

Of course in a language with builtin support for regular expression matching, `strspn()` makes little sense.  But when writing a rudimentary parser for a DSL in C, it's pretty nifty.

Comment: spotted: *p = 'c' is probably not what you ment ;-)

Answer (score 1):

It's based on the the ANSI C function `strspn()`.  It can be useful in low-level C parsing code, where there is no high-level string class.  It's considerably less useful in PHP, which has lots of useful string parsing functions.

Answer (score 1):

Well, by my understanding, its the same thing as this regex:

```
^[set]*
```

Where set is the string containing the characters to be found.

You could use it to search for any number or text at the beginning of a string and split.

It seems it would be useful when porting code to php.

Answer (score 1):

I think its great for blacklisting and letting the user know from where the error started. Like MySQL returns part of the query from where the error occured.

Please see this function, that lets the user know which part of his comment is not valid:

```
function blacklistChars($yourComment){

$blacklistedChars = "!@#$%^&*()";
$validLength = strcspn($yourComment, $blacklistedChars);
if ($validLength !== strlen($yourComment))
{

    $error = "Your comment contains invalid chars starting from here: `" . 
        substr($yourComment, (int) '-' . $validLength) . "`";

    return $error;
}

return false;
}

$yourComment = "Hello, why can you not type and $ dollar sign in the text?"; 
$yourCommentError = blacklistChars($yourComment);

if ($yourCommentError <> false)
echo $yourCommentError;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use it to capture the initial indent, for example, to normalize Markdown or YAML string:

```php
<?php

$content = <<<TEXT
    aaa
    aaa
        aaa
        aaa
    aaa
    aaa
TEXT;

$content = trim($content, "\n");
$dent = strspn($content, ' ');

if ($dent > 0) {
    // Remove the first indent
    $content = substr($content, $dent);
    // Remove other indent(s) after the first line
    $content = strtr($content, ["\n" . str_repeat(' ', $dent) => "\n"]);
}

echo $content;
```

Answer (score 0):

It is useful specificaly for functions like atoi - where you have a string you want to convert to a number, and you don't want to deal with anything that isn't in the set "-.0123456789"

But yes, it has limited use.

-Adam